# IPython Notebook NB convert formatting Footers?

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook

Using the NB convert with default options ("article") I am not getting a footer with page numbers?
I know nothing about LaTex but a brief look at the tpl files seems to indicate that I should get footers (maybe with page numbers?) The "book" option give nice footers, but is not a great format for other reasons...

I looked at the generated tex file and don't see anything for footers,, I did find that I can replace "unknown author" with my name.. :-)

Any guidence on how to modify either the generated tex file or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found if I added:

```
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

To the generated Tex file I get nicely formatted footers with page numbers...

I can include that in the original Ipython notebook souce file as a raw cell I put it in a new 1st cell and desinated it as raw,, and it works fine.

I still have to edit the 'unknown author' in the tex file though... Edit see the below comment to fix the Author field..

Answer (score 3):

You can set the author using

`ipython nbconvert --to latex --SphinxTransformer.author='John Doe' file.ipynb`